# VUEJS forEach array throws this is undefined

Tags: vue.js

I just don't get it why it won't work 'cause it was working fine before. Basically what I'm doing here is fetching posts with axios from my database and then trying to push those posts the array. This is where I get the posts:

`BlogAPI.js`

```
export const getPosts = () => {
   return API.get('/posts').then(response => {
       return response.data.posts;
   }).catch(error => {
       console.log('Something went wrong');
   })
}
```

`Home.vue`

```
import {getPosts} from '../blogApi';
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      postId: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    getPosts().then((result) => {
      result.forEach((element) => {
        this.posts.push(element)
      });
    });
  }
```

And it throws this error:

`Error in render: "TypeError: this is undefined"`

If I delete `mounted` function at all the error disappear. What causes this problem ?

**EDIT**
`TEMPLATE`

```
<template>
<div class="mainPage">
  <span v-if="this.$cookie.get('token')">
  <router-link class="float-right btn btn-success" to="create-post">Create Post</router-link>
  <button @click="logOut" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Log out</button>
  </span>
  <h4> Latest Articles</h4>
  <div class="posts d-flex justify-content-center">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li v-for="(post, index) in posts.slice().reverse()" :key="post._id"> 
          <strong><router-link :to="{path: '/post/' +  post.slug +'/' + post._id}">{{post.title}}</router-link></strong> 
        - {{post.intro}} 
        <i><small>{{ post.createdAt }}</small></i>
        <span v-if="this.$cookie.get('token')">
        <button @click="removePost(post._id, index)" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
        </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: What does the component's template look like?

Comment: Try changing `this.$cookie` to `$cookie`. My guess is the error is actually coming from the template and only appears when you have the mounted function because otherwise there are no items to render

Comment: Note that if your API call fails getPosts will return undefined. You would need to return an empty array inside your catch block.

Comment: @Connor You we're right. Now it works. Can u provide it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually coming from the template. It only appears when you have the mounted function because otherwise there are no posts to render. Try changing `this.$cookie` to `$cookie` in your template.

`this` is unnecessary in templates and can potentially cause issues. If you're using the vue eslint plugin, you can turn on [this rule](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/this-in-template.html) to catch these cases.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check it but I think you should try it like this below :

```
export const getPosts = () => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      API.get('/posts')
       .then(response => resolve(response.data))
       .catch(error => {
          console.log('Something went wrong');
          reject(error));
       })
   });
}
```

```
import { getPosts } from '../blogApi';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      postId: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    getPosts().then((result) => {
      result.forEach((element) => {
        this.posts.push(element)
      });
    });
  }
}
```

edited : I added a ")" I forgot
edited: added export default

Comment: Note the new Promise usage here is an antipattern. It is correct in the OP.

Comment: wait... you forgot export default {}